# Angular ui-router's ui-sref-active's parent not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I know that since 0.2.11 sref-active gets activated even if some of the nested children gets activated. However I'm getting weird behavior.

In this plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/Tdm2OBeIf8t56gs5qis2?p=preview everything works - when you go to "First section" and click through sub items, "First section" remains bold. But there is a problem - when you click on "First section", normally it should automatically select the first sub item. Currently you get nothing selected. It's the state 'index.first' instead of 'index.first.sub1'.

I tried to address this issue in this plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/rsiyROmprf73I3qEgAMp?p=preview by changing "First section"'s ui-sref from 'index.first' to 'index.first.sub1'.

From this:

`<li><a ui-sref="index.first" ui-sref-active="bold">First section</a></li>`

To this:

`<li><a ui-sref="index.first.sub1" ui-sref-active="bold">First section</a></li>`

And it breaks. If you click through sub items, only 'sub1' will get "First section" to be bold. Why is it happening? I want all three to make "First section" bold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a `.when()` setting. Check this updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rBFMiS6nhYVFc8FrBvsD?p=preview)

```
$urlRouterProvider.when('/index/first', '/index/first/sub1');
```

So, before the `'index.first'` is fired, we do redirect to its first *substate*

See:

- [`when()` for redirection](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing) *(small cite:)*

> Parameters:
>
> - what String | RegExp | UrlMatcher The incoming path that you want to redirect.
> - handler String | Function The path you want to redirect your user to.
>
> #### handler as String
>
> If handler is a string, it is treated as a redirect, and is interpolated according to the syntax of match (i.e. like String.replace() for RegExp, or like a UrlMatcher pattern otherwise).

```
app.config(function($urlRouterProvider){
    // when there is an empty route, redirect to /index   
    $urlRouterProvider.when('', '/index');

    // You can also use regex for the match parameter
    $urlRouterProvider.when(/aspx/i, '/index');
})
```

Comment: Awesome, it works. However, can you give any insight why simply routing to 'index.first.sub1' broke?

Comment: because, then the root state is not **`'index.first'`** anymore. It is a substate `index.first.sub1`, which became a root. And that's why if sibling **`index.first.sub2`** is selected, the root is not bold, because these are not parent/child ... but siblings sub1, sub2. Does it help? ;)